# Aggregating results from multiple unsupervised clustering studies

Tags: clustering, meta-analysis, unsupervised-learning, meta-learning

Is there a framework, similar to meta-analysis, to interpret or aggregate the results from multiple unsupervised clustering studies?

For example, take two studies on evaluating patients with heart failure to identify unique subgroups: 
https://www.jacc.org/doi/full/10.1016/j.jcmg.2016.10.012  
https://www.jacc.org/doi/full/10.1016/j.jcmg.2018.02.005

Can the results of both studies be combined in some manner?

Comment: You might try mvmeta... But I think you cannot reliably do it, as criteria for clustering are typically study specific... Only a patient-level meta-analysis is feasible in my opinion